# why std::integral_constant is necessary in exploding a std::tuple?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, generic-lambda

```
#include <iostream>

#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t... Idx>
auto make_index_dispatcher(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) 
{
    return [](auto&& f) { (f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Idx>{}), ...); };
}

template <std::size_t N>
auto make_index_dispatcher() 
{
    return make_index_dispatcher(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template <typename Tuple, typename Func>
void for_each(Tuple&& t, Func&& f) 
{
    constexpr auto n = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value;
    auto dispatcher = make_index_dispatcher<n>();
    dispatcher([&f, &t](auto idx) { f(std::get<idx>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))); });
}

int main() 
{
    for_each(std::make_tuple(1, 42.1, "hi"), [](auto&& e) {std::cout << e << ","; });
}
```

**Question 1>** Why I have to use `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Idx>{}` instead of simply `Idx` in the following statement? Based on my understanding, `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Idx>` is a type. Is it true that `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Idx>{}` is a value of `Idx`?

// OK

```
template <std::size_t... Idx>
auto make_index_dispatcher(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) 
{
    return [](auto&& f) { (f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Idx>{}), ...); };
}
```

// Error

```
template <std::size_t... Idx>
auto make_index_dispatcher(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) 
{
    return [](auto&& f) { (f(Idx), ...); };
}
```

Is it true that `std::get` expected compile-time constant expression while `Idx` is NOT a compile-time constant expression?

**Question 2>** Why we cannot pass `std::index_sequence` by reference?

// Error:
`auto make_index_dispatcher(std::index_sequence<Idx...>&)`

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why I have to use std::integral_constant{} instead of simply Idx in the following statement?

Because function arguments are never *constant expressions*. You can simply pass the indices as non-type template parameters instead, which are *constant expressions*. This works especially well with a C++20 template lambda:

```
template <std::size_t... Idx>
auto make_index_dispatcher(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) 
{
    return [](auto&& f) { (f.template operator()<Idx>(), ...); };
}

template <typename Tuple, typename Func>
void for_each(Tuple&& t, Func&& f) 
{
    constexpr auto n = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value;
    auto dispatcher = make_index_dispatcher<n>();
    dispatcher([&f, &t]<auto Idx>(){ f(std::get<Idx>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))); });
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ja0joH)

---

> Why we cannot pass std::index_sequence by reference?

You can, but you need to invoke your function with an lvalue like with any other non-`const` reference. This compiles:

```
template <std::size_t... Idx>
auto make_index_dispatcher(std::index_sequence<Idx...>&) 
{
}

int main()
{
    std::index_sequence<> is;        
    make_index_dispatcher(is);
}
```

Also, it's completely useless.

---

Also, your entire code can simply be:

```
int main() 
{
    std::apply([](auto&&... xs)
    {
        ((std::cout << xs << ','), ...);
    }, std::make_tuple(1, 42.1, "hi"));
}
```

Comment: I tried your code in the first section and it doesn't pass compiler error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token ')', expected 'expression'. I am using VS2017 v15.8.8

Answer (score 4):

> Why I have to use std::integral_constant{} instead of simply Idx in the following statement?
>
> Is it true that std::get expected compile-time constant expression while Idx is NOT a compile-time constant expression?

`std::get<>` expects a compile-time expression, but you are not actually using `idx` directly (which is not a compile-time expression).

`std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>` has a convenient `constexpr` conversion operator to `std::size_t` which returns `I`, so when you do:

```
std::get<idx>(...)
```

...you are actually doing `std::get<(std::size_t)idx>`, and `(std::size_t)idx` is a compile-time expression since the conversion operator is `constexpr`.

If you do not wrap `Idx` inside a `std::integral_constant`, the type of `idx` in the generic lambda will be `std::size_t`, and all the above will not work.

Answer (score 2):

> Why I have to use std::integral_constant{} instead of simply Idx in the following statement?

Just for fun...

What you say is true (as far I known) until C++17 (because the `std::get()` template argument must be known compile time and the use of `std::integral_constant` is an elegant way to pass a compile-time-known constant as type of an `auto` parameter in a generic (C++14 or later) lambda; see other answers for clearer explanations) but not true anymore (not necessarily you have to use `std::integral_constant`) starting from C++20.

In fact, C++20 introduces template lambdas, so you can rewrite your code as follows, passing the `Idx` values as template parameters and without `std::integral_constant`

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t... Idx>
auto make_index_dispatcher(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) 
{
    return [](auto&& f) { (f.template operator()<Idx>(), ...); };
} // ......................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   modified lambda call                        

template <std::size_t N>
auto make_index_dispatcher() 
{
    return make_index_dispatcher(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template <typename Tuple, typename Func>
void for_each(Tuple&& t, Func&& f) 
{
    constexpr auto n = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value;
    auto dispatcher = make_index_dispatcher<n>();
    dispatcher([&f, &t]<std::size_t I>() { f(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))); });
} // ..................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ template parameter added, argument removed

int main() 
{
    for_each(std::make_tuple(1, 42.1, "hi"), [](auto&& e) {std::cout << e << ","; });
}
```